# C# NPOI Formats Numbers as Text error

Tags: c#, export-to-excel

I am trying to store zip codes (US) into an excel file using C# and NPOI.

The zip code goes in as say "12345-6789" and i don't get the error in excel "the number in excel is formatted as text or preceded by an apostrophe" ( because it has the - char in there )

Then the next line has a zip of just "12345" and it does get the error since it is a number.  but...  I would rather it not.

here is some code:

```
        ICellStyle cellStyleString = eWorkBook.CreateCellStyle();
        cellStyleString.DataFormat = HSSFDataFormat.GetBuiltinFormat("General");  // also tried "@", "Text"

            IRow excelRow = eWorkSheet.CreateRow(0);
            foreach (var field in zipRecord.ItemArray)
                ICell newCell = excelRow.CreateCell(fieldNumber++);
                newCell.SetCellType(CellType.String);
                newCell.CellStyle = cellStyleString;
                newCell.SetCellValue(field.ToString());
```

Comment: Excel is correct, this *is* a number, and it's default is to warn you that since you stored the number as text, you can't do math with it.  Excel is primarily for math, after all.  The only way to avoid this is to disable the error checking rule.

Comment: ok...  Claies, I certainly believe it.  It is just that if I play around with it in excel, say by adding ' to the beginning I can get the warning to go away, but then I have a ' char in there for the users to call me up about...

Comment: Not sure about C#, but in Excel you can turn off that error-checking option either via Excel Options, or, in VBA, with `Application.ErrorCheckingOptions.NumberAsText = False`  But if you do it programmatically, you might to ensure it is returned to the original state when the workbook is closed.

Comment: something that I've seen common in the past to fool databases and the like is to store the `-` even if you don't have the extended info, so `12345-`.  Your users probably won't question that, especially if you have some that have the extended info.